# How can I get a jButton from its name?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

If i know just the name of a jButton, how can I get the button itself so I can set actionlistener and other stuffs?

I have a string which is the name of a jButton and i want to perform actions on the jbutton with that name if it exists?

Comment: Do you have the reference to the actual object? Where did the JButton come from? How did you create it?

Comment: How do you "name" the button?

Answer (score 1):

If i am right you want to get the name given to jbutton ie.,close or login etc.,I have retrieved the name of the text using `getText()`

Then try this

```
   JButton jb=new JButton();
     String name=jb.getText();
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev){
    if(ev.getActionCommand().equals(name){
      //This is the action of jButton.   
    } 
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

> I have a string which is the name of a jButton and i want to perform
>   actions on the jbutton with that name if it exists?

Your question is complete confusing, but to set name of a JButton or any other component we use `component.setName(String name)` function and to get the name of the component we use `component.getName()` function. Where component is any instance of `JComponent`. `JButton` is also a `JComponent`.

This is not preferable to me to rely on `event.getActionCommand()` to detect a source component of an event, rather try to make use of `event.getSource()` instead.